# unpacking a tuple with print

Tags: python

the second unpacking is not working with print, what is the reason?

```
for a in stok.iteritems():
...  c, b = a
...  print c, b
```

this one is valid

but this one is not

```
for a in stok.iteritems():
...  print c, b = a
```

Comment: In python if you want to print out a string followed by a variable you can use the following syntax: print 'Variable A: ', variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `c, b = a` is a *statement* and not an *expression* (i.e., it does something, but doesn't have a value) and therefore you can't print it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do an assignment (a = b) inside a print statement. They're both statements, so they have to be done separately.

If it helps, you can do: `for c, b in stok.iteritems():`.

Answer (score 1):

Does not make much sense. You want

```
for a in stok.iteritems():
...  print a
```

You can not mix assignments within a print...why would you think that this should work? Inventing new syntax?

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in the second piece of code, but it doesn't make sense: are you trying to print or are you trying to assign? You cannot print and assign in the same statement.

If you want to compare two numbers, use `==`. For example:

```
print a == b
```

will tell you whether a and b are equal or not.